# Page not found (404). Django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте. Изучаю django, не могу разобраться с этой ошибкой

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
http://127.0.0.1:8000/topics/%7B%25%20url%20'users:login'%20%25
Using the URLconf defined in MyBlog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='index']
^topics/$ [name='topics']
^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$ [name='topic']
^new_topic/$ [name='new_topic']
^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$ [name='new_entry']
^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$ [name='edit_entry']
^users/
The current path, topics/{% url 'users:login' %, didn't match any of these.
```

В папке MyBlog в ulrs.py прописано:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('MyBlogApp.urls', namespace='MyBlogApp')),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),  
]
```

В папке MyBlogApp urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),  
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    url(r'^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.new_entry,         
        name='new_entry'),
    url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, 
        name='edit_entry'), 
    ]
```

В папке users urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, 
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    ]
```

Почему пишет, что ни одно выражение не подходит?

Html который выводится в шапке страниц, в котором размещена ссылка на страницу авторизации

base.html

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'MyBlogApp:index' %}">My blog</a>
    <a href="{% url 'MyBlogApp:topics'%}">Topics</a>
        {% if user.authenticated %}
            Hello, {{ user.username }}.
            <a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">log out</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'users:login' %"}>log in</a>
        {% endif %}
</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Cама страница для авторизации:
login.html

```
{% extends 'MyBlogApp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login'%}" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button name="submit"> log in</button>
<input type="hidden" name="text" value="{% url 'MyBlogApp:index' %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Когда кликаешь на Log in, который в base.html (выше описание) вываливается ошибка "page not found"
логин есть только в base.html

Если открыть напрямую страницу `127.0.0.1:8000/users/login` страница отображается корректно, после ввода пользователя и пароля, опять вываливается с ошибкой `Page not found (404)`:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/%7B%25%20url%20'users:login'%20%25
Using the URLconf defined in MyBlog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, 
in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='index']
^topics/$ [name='topics']
^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$ [name='topic']
^new_topic/$ [name='new_topic']
^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$ [name='new_entry']
^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$ [name='edit_entry']
^users/ ^login/$ [name='login']
^users/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
The current path, users/login/{% url 'users:login' %, didn't match any of 
these.
```

Comment: Беглым взглядом можно заметить ошибку в шаблоне здесь `<a href="{% url 'users:login' %"}>log in</a>` в `base.html` `"` нужно за фигурные скобки вынести

Answer (score 1):

Ни одна из строк

```
url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
```

не соответствует url

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/topics/%7B%25%20url%20'users:login'%20%25`

Первый паттерн соответствует `http://127.0.0.1:8000/topics`

Второй паттерн соответствует urlям вроде `http://127.0.0.1:8000/topics/323432/`

`(?P<name\d+)` фактически задает именованную (из django можно будет обращаться по имени `name`) группу цифр длиной один или больше `(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

побробуйте добавить LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' в settings.py